# Xamarin forms - Convert XAML to c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I have a `ResourceDictionary` defined in XAML and I would like to convert it to c#.

I have trouble to convert the `OnPlatform` property and the Converters property.

How can I convert this?

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="VolosIconFont" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="VolosIconFont" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/VolosIconFont.ttf#VolosIconFont" />
    <On Platform="UWP, WinPhone" Value="Assets/Fonts/VolosIconFont.ttf#VolosIconFont" />
</OnPlatform>
```

And this?

```
<core:SelectedItemChangedEventArgsConverter x:Key="SelectedItemChangedEventArgsConverter" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the onplatform you can use this snippet whenever the *VolosIconFont* it's used:

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
    //reference your xaml item and apply your changes.
        break;
    case Device.Android:
        break;
    case Device.UWP:   
        break;
    case Device.macOS:
        break;
}
```

Looking at the converter, that line which you've posted it's just a reference of the C# Converter class. You don't need to map it into C#. It is there already.
You just need to set the binding programmatically whenever you want to use the converter:
e.g.

```
myLabel.SetBinding(myLabelProperty, new Binding("MyC#Property", null, new SelectedItemChangedEventArgsConverter(), null, null));
```

Don't know for sure why would you like to do this, but to me it seems to be the wrong approach. Try to stick with xaml. it's easier!